# JavaScript how to find how many multiples of 10 in a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box to enter any numbers. 
I need to check how many multiples of 10 are in that number.

for example, if the user types 11 output need to 1.

Also
 25 => 2
 34 => 3 etc....

Comment: the maths of it is `Math.floor(n/10)`

Comment: How does 34 have 3 multiples of 20?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean "how many multiples are in that number"? A number is a number, if it's a multiple of a number, it's a multiple of that number, stop :O

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, this should help you out:

```js
function multiplies() {
  var toCheck = document.getElementById('input').value;
  
  console.log("Multiplies: " + Math.floor(toCheck / 10));
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input"><button onclick="multiplies()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer demonstrates that, in javascript, there are always many ways to do a simple task

some, are just plain stupid

like this

```js
    var n = 121
    var s = n.toString()
    var a = s.split('');
    a.pop();
    var x = a.join('');
    var r = parseInt(x);
    console.log(r);
```

Comment: Your comment of `Math.floor(n/10)` was waaay cleaner. Also, this will break if you give a number > 99.

Comment: Creative, what about converting it into a bitmap and negating the 10?

Comment: `this will break if you give a number > 99` erm ... no, it works fine - by the way, this answer was a total pisstake :p

Comment: You're right. I read the logic wrong and thought you were reading the first character in stead of removing the last one. My bad.